# Element selection not working hybrid app but working with native app in Appium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-android

Am trying to select an element and adding click event using resource id

this is an hybrid app which developed in ionic

[ui automator selector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/241l2.png)

actually this is a tab

[tab image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrXYP.png)

then i wrote code like this

```
package android;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class app { 

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{

      File f= new File("src/123.apk");
      DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
      capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Galaxy Nexus API 23");
      capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");

      capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
      capabilities.setCapability("unicodeKeyboard", "true");
      capabilities.setCapability("resetKeyboard", "true");
      capabilities.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", "45000");
      capabilities.setCapability("app", f.getAbsolutePath());

      RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities); 

      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

      driver.findElement(By.id("tab-t0-1")).click();

 }
 }
```

[appium error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqCmP.png)

I have also add xpath method

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TabWidget/android.view.View[1][@resource-id='tab-t0-1']")).click();
```

but showing no element found error , actually same code working with native app with different resource - id

anything wrong here, please help

Comment: where have you added the above mentioned xpath ? Can you share the HTML also ?

Comment: what html? i didn't get you

Answer (score 0):

You have to changecontext to hybrid mode:

```
private boolean changeContext(String context) {
    boolean changeFlag = false;
    if (StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(context, "Native")) {
        context = "Native";
    } else if (StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(context, "Hybrid")) {
        context = "WEBVIEW_com";
    }
    if (StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(driver.getContext(), context)) return false;
    Set<String> contextName = driver.getContextHandles();
    for (String contexts : contextName) {
        if (StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(contexts, context)) {
            driver.context(contexts);
            changeFlag = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return changeFlag;
}
```

Comment: Thank You for your reply , 

find and changed my context like below

`driver.context("WEBVIEW_io.ionic.starter");`

`driver.findElementByName("information circle About").click();`
Then try to click this, but still geting error
`Failed to start Chromedriver session: A new session could not be created. (Original error: session not created exception: Chrome version must be >= 60.0.3112.0`